# How to display CSS/Sass source code in the Storybook for HTML on a Docs page?

Tags: html, css, sass, storybook

Is there any possibility of displaying CSS/Sass source for components using Storybook for the HTML?

I want to display Sass source codes in the Docs for components automatically but unfortunately, I don't see any possibility for that.

For example:

1. I have created ***ExampleComponent.stories.js*** file:

```
import exampleComponent from './ExampleComponent.html';
import './ExampleComponent.scss';

export default {
    title: 'Components/ExampleComponent',
    component: exampleComponent,
};

export const ExampleComponent= () => exampleComponent;
```

2. In the ***ExampleComponent.html*** I just put some simple HTML code:

```
<hr class='temp-test'>
```

3. In the ***ExampleComponent.html*** I just put some simple Sass code:

```
.temp-test {
    width: 500px;
    background: #ff0;
}
```

Preview:
[Example create component using HTML and Sass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbQp9.png)

On the Docs page I can see automatically generated HTML code from the importend HTML component. **Is such posibillity also for the CSS/Sass files?**

I have checked the Storybook [Source](https://storybook.js.org/docs/html/api/doc-block-source) and using it I can just paste the code to present it:
[Pasted Sass code preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSzJ0.png), [Pasted Sass source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTZJU.png).

But I am not satisfied with this solution because I have to remember to also change the code in this place.

Is there any possibility to display the Sass source code automatically from the imported Sass file on the Doc page?

I have also checked some addons and mainly their behaviour is exactly the same as described above Source so it is useless to install something additional to have the same result.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create a .mdx file, for example: ***ExampleComponentDocs.mdx*** and add this inside:

```
import { Meta, Source } from '@storybook/blocks';
import * as ExampleComponentStories from './ExampleComponent.stories';
import ExampleComponentStoriesCss from './ExampleComponent.scss';

<Meta of={ExampleComponentStories } />

<Source type="code" language="scss" code={ExampleComponentStoriesCss } />
```

Check for documentation here:

- https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/mdx
- https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/api/doc-block-source